# Is there a way to ensure an MSI installer updates the .exe file every time?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

Is there some easy, hassle-free way to get the MSI installation to always replace the .exe file (i.e. Primary Output) whenever the .exe file is more recent?

This is just basic and common sense. Wherever I search there are always complicated discussions about major and minor versions and patches. There must be some simple way to ensure the file gets replaced during an install. Otherwise, what is the MSI file actually doing during the whole installation procedure. It's like a fake install where nothing actually gets replaced/updated/upgraded.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Everything works in a "common sense" way as long as you increment the version number of the .exe. MSI trusts version info over more malleable aspects like a file's timestamp.

Comment: I see what you're saying and that makes sense. Thank you. So I have to  manually inrement the version every time I generate the MSI?

Comment: Usually it's part of an overall build system. (For example, the build increments the version number, puts it in include files, and every component gets its version number from them.)

Comment: The overall idea is to make MSI immune to the old problem where system dll files were overwritten with older file versions. Hence the new concept is that file version is king and overrides anything else for binaries. This all works fine just as long as you increment the version numbers, or at the very least don't decrement them.

Comment: but the version number does get incremented but still ignored. I have Assembly Version set to 1.1.*, and when I check the product version  via right click-->properties-->Details the version in the msi is higher than in the installed .exe yet running the msi doesn't replace the .exe.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. I am incrimenting the assembly and file version of my exe, but it never seems to overwrite the old version.

Comment: Assembly version != file version. Assemblies have both and the rules are different for files in versus out of the GAC. The file versioning rules are detailed at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on Assembly vs. File version. For two weeks now I've been manually incrementing the File Version everytime I want to release an update and it appears to do the trick.  Problem Solved!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with 'Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects' and deploying a Windows Forms application.

To do what you ask -

1. Increase the version number in the properties window for the installer project, it has 3 digits. A popup will appear asking about changing a product code, always choose yes.

Also in the same place, ensure that properties -
'DetectNewerInstalledVersion' is set to true and 'RemovePreviousVersions' is true

2. Increase the version numbers (there are four digits but apparently you need to increase one of the first three) at the end of the 'AssemblyInfo.cs' file in Solution Explorer in the 'properties' sub-folder of the project for each project where you need the compiled files to be updated. If you don't do this the new version will appear to install correctly but the old unchanged files may remain.

Provided all this is done, when a user installs it, the old version will be updated to the new version without having the uninstall the old version manually.

Answer (score 0):

In [File table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368596%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can set the Version column to "65535.65535.65535.65535". This way the file will always be overwritten, no matter what version it actually has.

This is not supported by Visual Studio, but you can edit the MSI with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4).

Comment: Note that this workaround, while accepted, can result in prompts for source during patching and other maintenance. This is because the recorded version for the file and the file's actual version will not match.

Answer (score 0):

Set your assembly version of your project to 1.0.* then it will automatically produce a new .exe version. You also need to make sure you increase the setup version, sadly there isn't a way to get this to auto-increment.