# uninstall previous version installed new version of setup project

Tags: windows, winforms, installation, setup-deployment

I create a setup project and installed in a windows system. Before going to install setup project I made setting as

```
DetectNewInstallerVersion = true
```

and

```
RemovePreviousVersion = True
```

I have also changed the version every time. But If I rebuild the setup project then again install the msi file it will not overwrite the existing file also it will create a new application in program features.  I want to uninstall the previous version and install new version without uninstall manually.

Comment: This question has a very good answer explaining the update procedure for installations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310908/installer-wont-overwrite-existing-app

Answer (score 9):

After several trials and attempts, even by reading the replies of this community, I try to give you a more complete answer than I have found.

1) Right click on your solution project, then *Properties*. In the *Application* menù keep in mind the version of the Framework (the setup must have the same version) and then click **Assembly Information**. In here, write your custom version (*Assembly Version* and *File Version* should be identical) using the first three blocks (because the setup property doesn't have the fourth block), for example 1.0.0.

2) In the *Explore Solutions* panel enter inside the treeview of your setup project in the **Detected Dependencies** folder, then double click in **Microsoft .NET Framework** and set

```
Version = .NET Framework (X.X.X)
```

where *X.X.X* is the version number of the Framework used in the solution project.

3) Right click on your project solution, then *Properties*. Set:

```
DetectNewerInstalledVersion = True
RemovePreviousVersions = True
Version = //the number used in the assembly at the point 1)
```

It will appear the message *It is recommended that the ProductCode be changed if you change the versione. Do you want to do this?* Click **Yes**.

4) Right click on your project solution, then **Recompile**. If the *Output* panel doesn't reports any errors, you can go in the debug folder (usually *C:\Users\YOURPCNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\YOURPROJECTNAME\YOURPROJECTNAME\bin\Debug*) and use the .msi or the .exe files to install your project.

When you need to change the version number, run the four points above again.
I use this mode for my projects and with .msi file has always worked.

Answer (score 2):

In combination with what Wiccio has posted, I also found that setting the property **InstallAllUsers** to **true**

```
InstallAllUsers = True
```